# Double-clicking twice in a row not registering on react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, dom-events

I have some very simple code in a functional react component:

```
const example = () => (
    <div onDoubleClick={() => { console.log('fired'); }}>
      test element
    </div>
);
```

Double-clicking once logs `'fired'` as expected, but double-clicking twice in a row without delay does not log it twice. I have to wait a fraction of a second before double-clicking again if I want it to fire a second time. Is there some sort of built-in rate limiting happening here?

I will note that the same thing happens on the interactive example in the MDN docs for the `dblclick` event - if you double click while the example is transitioning, it doesn't recognize the input and ignores it. Is this happening at the browser level? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Maybe this is a  browser-level feature rather than a React-specific one. `click debouncing` or `double-click prevention.`

Comment: @ThavasAntonio is maybe right but also keep it mind that javascript runs on a single thread that is blocked until the specific task is done. The second double click doesnt work because the first is still "running". Someone confirm pls 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the onClick method instead:

```
const example = () => (
   <div onClick={(e) => {
        !(e.detail % 2) && console.log("fired");
      }}
    >
      test element
    </div>
);
```

`e.detail` will be the number of times in a row that the event has fired. If you pause then trigger the event again, it will reset to `1`.

Comment: Oh my god this works, wow! Where did you find out about `event.detail`? Where is that documented?

Comment: Mozilla covered it perfectly:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Answer (score 0):

well, this has nothing to do with React as well as the browser. but this behavior is related to how **JavaScript Mouse Events works** .

**click event on  an element   :**

**1 -** The `mousedown` when you depress the mouse button on the element

**2 -** The `mouseup`  hen you release the mouse button on that element

**3-** When these combination are detected you fire The `click event`

however `double click event`, It takes two click events to cause it :

**1-**  mousedown

**2-** mouseup

**3-** click

**4-**  mousedown

**5-**  mouseup

**6-**  click

**7 -**  dblclick

the problem you faced when you double-clicked twice in a row without delay. javascript runs the first demonstration (clicks) four times  rather than two  dbclick